# Updating the ListFragment

Tags: android

```
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_schedule, container, false);

        // array adapter + list fragment
        arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(getActivity(),
                R.layout.simple_list_item_1_custom,
                schedules.get(getArguments().getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER) - 1)); //

        arrayAdapter.setNotifyOnChange(true);
        setListAdapter(arrayAdapter);
        return rootView;
    }
```

This is the onCreateView of my class that extends ListFragment, I am trying to update the contents of the list from my activity, so far I've tried clearing the arrayAdapter and calling notifyDataSetChanged on it, and it doesn't work. The only way I can get my list to update is if I swipe two tabs and go back again, then it shows all the changed values. Any suggestions?

Comment: Where are you calling `notifyDataSetChanged` and when do you want the list adapter to be updated?

Comment: I have set an OnClick for my floating action button, when it is clicked, it adds a value to the schedules (it's an ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>), everything shows after I restart the app (all data is saved to DB)

Answer (score 0):

This is the onCreateView of your fragment. This is fired every time when you create your fragment or swipe between tabs. As I understand, you just add values to the db onClick and when you go and come back your fragment you see the new values.

Please, try adding new values to your adapter on onClick button then try updating your list in the same scope with the NotifyDataChanged mechanisim of the adapter.

If I get wrong idea about whay you are doing pleas share more code.

Comment: PlaceholderFragment.arrayAdapter.clear();
        
PlaceholderFragment.arrayAdapter.addAll(schedules.get(mViewPager.getCurrentItem()));

PlaceholderFragment.arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

I use this code after adding the new values to the schedules ArrayList, it does nothing.